# Advanced Filter to copy data to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Workbook with a search interface on one Worksheet and a database on another Worksheet.
this is the code I use to do an Advanced Filter on the database which returns the values on the search interface worksheet:

```
Private Sub Find_Click()
    Sheet2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=Sheet4.Range("V1:AE2"), CopyToRange:=Sheet4.Range("E1:T1"), Unique:=False
End Sub
```

I am now trying to split the 2 worksheets into 2 workbooks. So the Advanced Filter would be performed on the data contained in Workbook "Data" and the results returned to the Workbook "SearchInterface".
The 2 workbooks would always be opened at the same time.

I tried inserting variables:

```
Private Sub Find_Click()
    Set wbSearch = ThisWorkbook
    Set wbData = Workbooks("GAL_db.xlsx")
    
        wbData.Sheet2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy,
        CriteriaRange:=wbSearch.Sheet4.Range("V1:AE2"), CopyToRange:=wbSearch.Sheet4.Range("E1:T1"), Unique:=False

End Sub
```

Getting Syntax Error on

```
wbData.Sheet2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy
```

I tried many things but nothing works. Not being too knowledgeable, I'm pretty much shooting in the dark. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

**==UPDATE===**

thanks for the input Rory!
I changed the code as suggested to this:

```
Private Sub Find_Click()
    Set wbData = Workbooks("GAL_db.xlsx")
    
        wbData.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy,
        CriteriaRange:=Sheet4.Range("V1:AE2"), CopyToRange:=Sheet4.Range("E1:T1"), Unique:=False

End Sub
```

Now I'm getting again a syntax error with:

```
wbData.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy,
```

and `Private Sub Find_Click()` is highlighted in yellow...

Comment: error message and on which line?

Comment: You can't use the codename of a worksheet in a different workbook (unless you have a reference set) so you need to use `wbData.Sheets("Sheet2")` rather than `wbData.Sheet2` (adjusting the sheet name as necessary).

Comment: after changing the `Sheets("Sheet2")` i'm now getting a compile error: Expected Expression after "CriteriaRange:="

Comment: You don't need `wbSearch.Sheet4` but just `Sheet4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, through trial and error I got it working! Yeeey! Don't know why, but it only works if I reference the Sheet4 as Worksheets(1). Here is the code that works for my purpose:

```
Private Sub Find_Click()

    Dim wbData As Range
    Dim wbCriteria As Range
    Dim wbExtract As Range

    Set wbData = Workbooks("GAL_db.xlsx").Worksheets("data").Range("A1")
    Set wbCriteria = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("V1:AE2")
    Set wbExtract = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("E1:T1")

    wbData.CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=wbCriteria, CopyToRange:=wbExtract, Unique:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a combination of the 2 solutions you had...

```
Private Sub Find_Click()
Set wbSearch = ThisWorkbook
Set wbData = Workbooks("GAL_db.xlsx")

        wbData.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy,
        CriteriaRange:=wbSearch.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("V1:AE2"), CopyToRange:=wbSearch.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("E1:T1"), Unique:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: thx for the input Rude Dawg! but I'm still getting that darn Syntax error on line `wbData.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy,`.  should I be approaching this task another way instead?

Comment: what is the exact error you are receiving?  Maybe a screenshot?

Comment: getting the "Compile Error: Syntax Error"