# VBA Macro Filter And Copy To New Tab

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro which will insert a new column flagging particular cells. 
I want it to then create two tabs based on the values.
My macro is giving me an `error 1004 invalid name` for sheet or chart

My code is

```
Sub Groups()
Columns("L:L").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("L2").Select
Range("L2:L" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=IF(OR(RC[-1]=27594,RC[-1]=27601),""Flag"",""Groups Excluding Flag"")"
Range("L1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Test"
Columns("L:L").Select
   Selection.Copy
   Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
      :=False, Transpose:=False

Dim c As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim LR As Long

    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("A1:Q" & LR)

   Range("L2:L" & LR).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("AM1"), _ 
Unique:=True
   Columns("L:L").Select
   Selection.Copy
   Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
      :=False, Transpose:=False

   For Each c In Range([AM2], Cells(Rows.Count, "AM").End(xlUp))
    With rng
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=c.Value
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = c.Value
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End With
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = c.Value

Comment: What is the value of `c` when it errors? Presumably it is not a valid name for a sheet.

Comment: It should take the ""Flag"",""Groups Excluding Flag"" values? So either the first or second option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the issue is with this line of code             `Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = c.Value`  If I remember correctly, excel doesn't like for you to add a sheet and name it in the same line of code.  I would suggest creating and referencing the sheets like so

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    Set ws2 = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    ws1.Range("A1").Value = "WS1"
    ws2.Range("A1").Value = "WS2"
```

Comment: Thanks, how exactly do I incorporate that into my existing code?

Comment: Not arguing against your answer but note that Excel does allow you to add and name a sheet in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Change `Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = c.Value` to the following:

```
With ThisWorkbook
    Dim oW As Worksheet: Set oW = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
    oW.Name = c.Value
End With
oW.Paste
```

Comment: Gave me the same error, with the final line of your code

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add and rename your new sheet before paste to it:

```
For Each c In Range([AM2], Cells(Rows.Count, "AM").End(xlUp))
        With rng
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=c.Value
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            Activesheet.Name = c.Value
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End With
Next c
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error with Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))

Comment: Sorry, please change to this code: Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

Comment: Thanks, I am now getting an error with  Range("L2:L" & LR).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("AM1"), Unique:=True                I edited my code to what I am now currently running. Noticed an issue with a column reference.

Comment: You need to add CriteriaRange before CopyToRange.

Comment: You can find at this link to get more info how to code advanced filter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407599/excel-vba-advanced-filter-to-copy-data-to-another-workbook